# getting django url to work with parameters

Tags: django, url, view

I am using an external database rather than ORM. I am writing a test application and when the test is submitted, I would like the user to be redirected to a URL which has their test ID appended to the url and the page should display their test results. For example, "http://domain/testplatform/123" where 123 is the test ID which comes from the external database. The db also holds all the test results for that test ID and I get and use these values in a template. But I can't get the app to append the test ID to the URL. Here is my code.

url.py

```
from testplatform import views
...
(r'^testplatform/(\d+)/$', views.testcriteria, 'testsubmit'),
(r'^testplatform/$', views.testcriteria),
...
```

This bit, r'^testplatform/(\d+)$'. is where I would like to append the values in testsubmit to the URL. The r'^testplatform/$' takes the user to a form I have created which they fill out to initiate a test.

views.py

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from testplatform.test_db import tests
...
def testcriteria(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TestCriteriaForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      ...
      cd = form.cleaned_data
      t_testname = cd['testname']
      ...
      sql = tests()
      testsubmitid = sql.tbl_test_name(t_testname)
      ...

      testsubmit = dict(testsubmitid=testsubmitid, testcriteria=testcriteria)
      testsubmit.update(csrf(request))
      return render_to_response('testsubmitted.html',testsubmit)
```

I have confirmed that I am getting a value back from testsubmitid - this returns the test ID. The testcriteria values come from another query from the external database that holds information from regarding what has been tested.

However when I submit the form the page just directs to testsubmitted.html but the url is just "http://domain/testplatform"

Should I create a new view for the results page and use something like this to redirect the user to a results page?

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("testresults.views.results", args=testsubmit))
```

Can anyone help tell me why this isn't working?

Thanks - Oli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting that particular error, since you didn't provide the traceback. You also haven't shown any code that would do the redirection to `/testplatform/123`, so I can't help with that. But there is certainly an error: that view doesn't take a parameter for the ID. You probably need to do something like:

```
def testcriteria(request, submit_id=None):
```

Comment: I think my logic here is flawed and this won't work as it stands. So something needs changing, but I cannot figure out what. After the form is submitted, the action is to redirect as follows,  <form action="/testplatform/"  method="post">. As hopefully I have shown in the url.py, the view for testcriteria() then handles the cleaned_data which is when I collect the post data and after that I am trying to use render_to_response('testsubmitted.html'...) Is this logic flawed?

Comment: But there's no redirection going here anywhere! You submit the form to /testplatform/, so that's the URL that processes the form and renders the template. How are you expecting the /123/ to appear in the URL? If you want to go to a different URL, you need to actually redirect to it.

Comment: So should I create a new view and then use something like this: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("testresults.views.results", args=[testsubmit])).